# Как правильно распарсить XML с двумя вложенными тэгами?

Tags: xml, парсер, golang

Не могу распарсить XML файл вида:

```
const xmlstr  = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <users>
 <test>
  <user type="admin">
   <name>Elliot</name>
 </user>
 <user type="reader">
  <name>Fraser</name>
 </user>
 </test>
</users>`

type Users struct {
 XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"users"`
}
type Test struct {
 Test    []Test    `xml:"test"`
 Users   []User       `xml:"user"`
}
type User struct {
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"user"`
 Type    string   `xml:"type,attr"`
 Name    string   `xml:"name"`}
```

Распарсить удаётся вариант без тега `<test>`: https://play.golang.org/p/KCX_bWOkZE.
Как дописать структуры что бы удалось распарсить XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный вариант такой:

```
type Users struct {
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"users"`
 Test Test `xml:"test"`
}
type Test struct {
 Users   []User   `xml:"test>user"`
}
type User struct {
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"user"`
 Type    string   `xml:"type,attr"`
 Name    string   `xml:"name"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_993jsypNq